# $_SESSION variable not passing through after paypal: Objective is to email the user

Tags: php, email, session, paypal

Only the email portion isn't working because the `$stub` and `$user` variables are lost between php pages or switches (whichever they are). The tags close, then html begins, then a new set of php tags are opened. Now surprisingly, the `$_SESSION['userid']` works great and that was set at the beginning of the file. Not sure why `$stub` and `$user` do not work. I tried using `$_SESSION['user']` for a new variable called $globalstub and renamed that as well but negative on that one. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of `session` does not help,you will need to use [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) in Pay Pal.

Instant Payment Notification (**IPN**) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, like fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status.

Get sample codes [here](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples)

Comment: well i had paid someone to write this for me since i did not want to deal with the paypal part of the process. i wrote my original code minus all the paypal stuff. is it absolutely necessary to use IPN here?

Comment: Yes,  it's recommended to use IPN for customizing email notifications